# Remove the first < tr > from an ajax response

Tags: jquery

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "url",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data){
            var temp = $(data).find('tbody');
            var tr = temp.children();
            $('tbody').last().append(tr);
        }
    });
```

The response would look like:

```
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

How would I remove the first < tr >?

Answer (score 1):

just use remove on the first element, as in `tr.first().remove();`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "url",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data){
        var tr = $(data).find('tbody tr:not(:first)');
        $('div').last().append(tr);
    }
});
```

Comment: @ECMAScript do you have a table there, or just its rows? If it's only the rows, stop looking for them.

Comment: Try another approach then. Is the "response" in your question what `data` contains, or what `tr` contains, it's a bit unclear ?

Comment: If you only have the rows, you can just forget about it. You can't append table rows to a DIV ?

Comment: Oh I made a mistake, I'm not appending to a div, I'm appending to a tbody, just adding extra rows. The code you currently have up strips the tr tags and appends all td tags.

Comment: Nope, `tr.not(':first')` wouldn't strip the `tr` tags and insert just the `td`'s, invalid code or getting the wrong elements would. Changed it again, but without knowing how any of the markup really looks, it's just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
temp.find("tr:eq(0)").remove();
```